# Docker Build - unknown instruction: PYTHON3

Tags: python, docker

I've tried to build a docker image following the documentation on Docker Hub. Below is the docker image contents:

```
FROM alpine:latest
              # This sets the image we start building from
RUN apk add --update \          # first update
   python3 \                    # Install Python
   py-pip \                    # Install pip
 && pip install flywheel-sdk \ # Use pip to install the flywheel SDK
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*    # Cleanup install files

ENV FLYWHEEL=/flywheel/v0
 # Setup default flywheel/v0 directory

RUN mkdir -p ${FLYWHEEL}        # Create that directory
COPY run.py ${FLYWHEEL}/run.py  # Copy in our runscript into the docker image

ENTRYPOINT ["python run.py"]    # Set an entrypoint
```

when I do `docker build` I get an error that looks like Python is unable to load from the `alpine:python` image.

```
(base) isabelannwingert@Isabels-MacBook-Pro PET_gear % docker build -t isabelannwingert36/alpine-python-3:0.1.0 ./
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.144kB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 4: unknown instruction: PYTHON3
```

When I re-do `docker pull alpine:latest` it tells me that everything is up-to-date, yet I also do not see it in my repository on Docker Hub.

Is there anything else I can try? (I'm new to Docker Hub so excuse my naivete).

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't support same line comments. Hence the issue. Please rewrite your code like this.

```
# This sets the image we start building from
FROM alpine:latest
# First update, Install Python, Install pip
# Use pip to install the flywheel SDK, Cleanup install files
RUN apk add --update python3 py-pip \
  && pip install flywheel-sdk \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Setup default flywheel/v0 directory
ENV FLYWHEEL=/flywheel/v0

# Create that directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FLYWHEEL}
# Copy in our runscript into the docker image
COPY run.py ${FLYWHEEL}/run.py

# Set an entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["python run.py"]
```

Comment: Please accept if this solves your problem so that others won't have to check this question.